# Correctly animate buttons which have elevation/drop shadow set

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-animation

I'm currently coding a simple memory game for android and ran into this problem:

I wanted to animate my card (which is an image button) to flip around. This works. What however doesn't work is, the drop shadow assigned to the button through the elevation property. It doesn't display as expected and introduces graphical glitches and small performance issues.

You can have a look at the glitches here:
[graphical glitches on the drop shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xKr2.png)

The buttons are defined in my **activity_memory.xml** file like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<ImageButton
  android:layout_width="70dp"
  android:layout_height="70dp"
  android:id="@+id/btn_1_1"
  android:layout_column="0"
  android:background="@drawable/zelda0"
  android:layout_margin="2dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:onClick="button11clicked"
  android:elevation="5dp" />
<!-- ... -->
```

the animation is specified in my drawable/animator **flipcardtoback.xml** file like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Rotate. -->
<objectAnimator
  android:valueFrom="0"
  android:valueTo="180"
  android:propertyName="rotationY"
  android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
  android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

The code triggers an **animation function** which flips the card and halfway through the animation duration it switches the background image of the button from the frontside image to the backside image of the card.

I guess the way I flip the card isn't the problem. It's just the drop shadow which glitches. I don't really know how to fix this, as I've tried to make a new drawable resource forming a drop shadow and assign this to the background property of the button. This however results in the image obviously not being displayed.

Is there any way to fix this so it animates the drop shadow correctly or in a way which is more pleasing to the eye?

Answer (score 0):

Scale down one button and a scale up the reverse.  This way the button stays flat and Android has no trouble displaying a shadow.

```
public static final AccelerateInterpolator 
    ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
public static final DecelerateInterpolator
    DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();
```

...

```
private void animateFromTo(final Button buttonLeave, final Button buttonArrive) {
    buttonArrive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    buttonLeave.animate()
            .setDuration(250)
            .scaleY(0)
            .setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    buttonLeave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    buttonArrive.setScaleY(0);
                    buttonArrive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonArrive.animate()
                            .setDuration(250)
                            .scaleY(1)
                            .setInterpolator(DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR)
                            .setListener(null)
                            .start();
                }
            }).start();
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps, even thought it's a little late! Seen a better answer?